# C# Get relative path in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, relative-path

I have 2 projects Project A , Project B , 
project A has a reference to project B , project A is an executable.

```
  Project A --> Project B
```

inside project B there is a directory called "MyFolder"

so the soulotion hierarchy is as follows :

```
    MySolution 
       -  A
       -  B 
          - MyFolder
```

how do i get a Relative Path to MyFolder from with in project A(Executable).

I found allot of answer which state the following  :

```
  sring path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInBProject)).Location;
```

The path i got back from this is the path to B.dll in A's bin\debug 
,how can i retrieve a path with in that .dll .

Edit :

iv'e also tried :

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInBProject));
        FileStream fs = assembly.GetFile(@"MyFolder\myFile"); 

        and 

         FileStream fs = assembly.GetFile("MyFolder\myFile");  

        and 

         FileStream fs = assembly.GetFile("myFile");
```

fs i always null.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, isn't the folder consider `virtual` if created under VS for that particular project? I mean, once a DLL is created from that project, there's no folder, its just a component. Fav this, excited to see the answer ;)

Comment: yes i think that's correct the question is how to retrieve a file from the compiled dll

Comment: Looks to me that this folder is an implementation detail of B.  Which should therefore exposes a public static property to return the path.  Either way, use Assembly.Location

Answer (score 2):

Is [Uri.MakeRelativeUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you're looking for?

```
string pathA = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string pathB = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInBProject)).Location;

Uri pathAUri = new Uri(pathA);
Uri pathBUri = new Uri(pathB);

string relativePath = pathAUri.MakeRelativeUri(pathBUri).OriginalString;
string relativeMyFolder = Path.Combine(relativePath, "MyFolder");
```

Update

You can use the [Assembly.GetFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns a FileStream. `FileStream` has a `Name` property you could use in the code above.

Comment: is pathA suppose to be :

   string pathA = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

?

Comment: can this work ? 
the path would be   "B.dll\MyFolder"

Comment: You can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `pathB` to ignore the `B.dll`.

Comment: well it doesn't matter if i removed the .dll or not 

path "B\MyFolder\MyFile" from the executing code in A can't locate the file

Comment: I've added an update. If you want an actual file (or files), you can use Assembly.GetFile("nameOfFile") where Assembly is `Assembly B`. I haven't tested it, but seems like it's what you want.

Comment: `Null` means the file was not found. I don't have a dev machine to hand to test it out but if the file exists, it should work. You don't need to pass in the path, just the file name. Try searching for the file with and without the extension as part of the name. (e.g. "myFile.ext" and "myFile"). Alternatively, use `Assembly.GetFiles()` and go through the array that's returned and see if your file is in there.

Comment: of course Null means that it was not found , that's why i pointed it out , 
assembly.GetFiles() returns an array with one item , there sits our good all friend , 

"c:\\users\\eran\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\A\\bin\\Debug\\B.dll"

Comment: Have you made the file a resource in Assembly B?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some reason that you can't do this, I recommend opening the Properties Window* and setting the `Build Action` property to `Embedded Resource` and making sure that `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Do not copy`. You can then use [Assembly.GetFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access it.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInBProject));
using (FileStream fs = assembly.GetFile("myfile"))
{
    // Manipulate the FileStream here
}
```

*With the file selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or right-click on the file and select `Properties`