# How to get a relative path of a dll?

Tags: c#, path

I have imported a Dll used for Com object.

How can i get the relative path to that dll?
is it even possible?

I'm using .Net 4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Get relative path in referenced assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955109/c-sharp-get-relative-path-in-referenced-assembly) amazing what you can find when you use `GOOGLE` @RayOldProf

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var absolutePath = @"c:\dev\myApp\relativePathStartFolder\animals\birds\duck.dll";
var relativePathStartIndex = absolutePath.IndexOf("relativePathStartFolder");
var relativePath = absolutePath.Substring(relativePathStartIndex);
```

*hides under table*